# How can I highlight a portion of the text of a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, highlight

What I would like to do is, if my detailed view gets called I would like to highlight just a part of the text of the `UITextView` element.

Let's say the text within the `UITextView` is: `blatextbla`. Then I would like to highlight dynamically only `text` or `late` or whatever comes to the user's mind.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't highlight a text in a `UITextView`.

Instead you can go with [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the ranges within your text where the text to be highlighted starts and ends then use:

```
NSRange selection = [yourNSString rangeOfString:@"late"];
if( selection.location != NSNotFound ){
   myTextView.selectedRange =  selection;
}
```

I've never tried to select multiple ranges within a `UITextView`, so not sure if that's possible. I doubt it's possible...

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

This is a built-in function through which you can find and replace text in a TextView.