# iOS UITextView Text Highlighting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

I have an UITextView and I want to highlight specific words,
I like the iBooks app text highlighting, is there any way to use the same style?
How can I use OpenGL to highlight text?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940212/how-can-i-highlight-a-portion-of-the-text-of-a-uitextview

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use NSAttributeString class, if I understood you right. Here's the docs
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributedString
It allows you to change font, size, color etc within a single NSString object. (for example you can type a simple regex expression to change color or set **bold** of a certain characters)

Comment: Thanks, how can I apply it to my UITextView?

Comment: It seems that you should do all stuff you want with the NSString obtained from yourTextView.text, isn't it?
    NSAttributeString * coolString = [[NSAttributeString alloc] initWithString:yourTextView.text]; and go on!

Comment: if, again, I understood you in the right way because you provided very little information about your question.

Comment: and also take a look at the UITextViewDelegate's methods you likely will do your stuff in one of them...